# Bootstrap navbar width / max-width

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My bootstrap navbar links are many, so it wraps (I think at 970px).

I don't want it to wrap, the width of the links in total are about 1020px.  I've searched high and low for the answer :(

When I add a width of 1020px to `.navbar .navbar-collapse` the nav bar is now a little off center.

How can I get it to be `1020px width` and stay centered?

```
 .navbar .navbar-collapse {
  text-align: center;
      width:1020px;
}
```

Then how do I get the navbar to not wrap but to collapse for tablet?

**Edit:**

Here's the html - basically (link names removed).

```
<!-- NAVIGATION -->
<div class="container">
    <!-- Fixed navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#welcome">LINK 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#who">LINK 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#benefits">BLAH BLAH</a></li>
            <li><a href="#outline">BLAH BLAH BLAH</a></li>
            <li><a href="#package">THE BLAH BLAH BLAH</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#faq">BLAH</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#testimonials">BLAH BLAH BLAH</a></li>
            <li><a href="#bonuses">BLAH</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#buy" class="buyNow">BLAH</a></li> 

          </ul>
          
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>
<!-- End Fixed navbar -->
</div>
```

Here's the additional css:

```
.navbar .navbar-nav {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  vertical-align: top;
}

 .navbar .navbar-collapse {
  text-align: center;
      width:1024px;
      white-space: nowrap;
        border: 3px dotted #ff00ff;
}


/* navbar */
.navbar-default {
    background-color: #f2b32a;
    border-color: #C89321;

    font-size: 13px;
    letter-spacing: -0.9px;
}

/* link */
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: #fff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
    color: #333;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
    color: #555;
    background-color: #E7E7E7;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
    color: #555;
    background-color: #D5D5D5;
}
.navbar {
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #C89321; 
/*   visibility: hidden; */
}

.buyNow{

    font-size: 19px;
}
```

Comment: Can you give me your html code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:
   white-space: nowrap;
Also if you reduce your html/css to a minimum that still has a problem and post it - others will be able to check and confirm the solution.

Comment: Nowrap was the bizniz, it's still off to the right by about 20 to 30 pixels. Curious.

Comment: In that case I can propose not a solution but an alternative: Since you have many menus - reorganize some of them into a group or two and put them in a dropdown.  If you reduce the number of navbar pills/selections to 7 - everything seems to work fine. See [link]https://jsfiddle.net/r9xn3s2r/3/ <br /> And a general suggestion: do not design a site that requires 1024 pixels for a 768px tablet world.

Comment: Haha, thanks :D Art director requests it like this :)   For the tablet I'm thinking that the images can reduce % and the navbar collapse, what do you think?

Comment: I do not think until I try things. :-) And for your art director - try going for a compromise: if the screen is wider than XXXX - use full menu, if not: put some stuff into a drop down. That is what media queries are for. No? <p> Also maybe (http://www.twitterbootstrap.net/forum/forum.php) is another good place to ask.

Comment: Cool, so you jump off a bridge and then you think about whether it was a good idea or not.  Good suggestions and link though. Thank you! :D

Comment: If you had noticed a smiley you might have understood me better. What I meant was that I have to get my hands on the code/lib and try stuff to see how it is intended to work. Then as a step 2 - I try to included it in the project related "stuff" and see if it actually fits. Even then it does not always fit. :-( .... and so on.... Good luck to you.

Answer (score 0):

Why 1020px and not a standard 1024px, you can decrease the font size a bit to see what happens. But there isn't really much I can help you with, without a screenshot

Comment: Good idea. It's off by about 25 to 30 pixels right now, to the right.